# How to share code between different Classes?

Tags: java, android, interface, abstract-class, subclassing

Hi I have fairly complex application requiring subclassing of "Activity", "Service" and "FragmentActivity" in Android (but this question is still valid in pure Java as well)

[image]

Each of the 3 classes is extended with a set of utilities in "My Layer" e.g. a specific way to display a Toast or a specific way to handle a configuration or to read files on disk, etc.

Right now I created a common **interface** (MyUtilities) for all 3 types of classes e.g.

```
    public class MyActivity extends Activity implements MyUtilities
    public class MyFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity implements MyUtilities
    public class MyService extends Service implements MyUtilities


   public class MyActivity1 extends MyActivity
   public class MyFragmentActivity1 extends MyFragmentActivity
   public class MyService1 extends MyService
```

but this makes me end up copying and pasting the common methods for all 3 classes since I can't define fields and methods in the interface. Is there a better way to do that? Copying code is extremely error prone in the long term.

I looked at abstract classes but not sure how to use them in this case. Ideally what I need it a "double extend" like

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity, MyUtilities
```

which is obviously not allowed but which would solve my problem.

Ideas please?

Thanks!

PS: I'm already using static methods on common classes wherever possible

As requested, here'a a simple example. Each of the 3 objects need to be able to support a configuration field and each contains the following

```
private Configuration config

public Configuration getConfiguration(){return config;}

public void setConfiguration(Configuration cfg){this.config=cfg;}
```

Going with an Interface helps in requiring that the methods are there but I still need to copy and paste code which I don't really like.

Comment: Please share more code, the answer is just extracting logic in a separated class's method.  However, for a better help share your code.

Comment: Thanks, I added a simple example in the main text

Answer (score 0):

**Take a look at this approach:**

The idea is to create your `Custom Activity` class that will extends `Activity` and implements `MyUtilities` interface.  This way, Android layer will understands your Custom Class as Activity and your layer as MyActivity as well as `MyUtilities`.

```
public class CustomActivity extends Activity implements MyUtilities {
   private Configuration config

   public Configuration getConfiguration(){return config;}

   public void setConfiguration(Configuration cfg){this.config=cfg;}
}
```

Android Layer will understand the instances of class `MyActivity` as `Activity`.

Your layer will understand the instances of class `MyActivity` as `CustomActivity` as well as MyUtilities.

```
public class MyActivity extends CustomActivity {

}
```

**Hope this helps!**

Comment: Thanks, The problem I have when doing that is when I try to do the same for e.g. a Service, which cannot extend CustomActivity in this case. Or am I missing something on that?

Comment: maybe you can try a decorator pattern?